# Python SciPy linprog optimization fails with status 3

Tags: python, scipy

Trying to minimize a simple linear function with linprog. The coefficients are the elements of `arr2` multiplied by -1. There are only inequality constraints for each variable, such as -1 <= x1 <= 1, -2 <= x2 <= 2 and so on.

If a choose not to specify bounds in `linprog`:

```
from scipy.optimize import linprog
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

numdim = 28

arr1 = np.ones(numdim)
arr1 = - arr1

arr2 = np.array([
19.53,
128.97,
3538,
931.8,
0.1825,
150.88,
10315,
0.8109,
3.9475,
3022,
31.77,
10323,
110.93,
220,
2219.5,
119.2,
703.6,
616,
338,
84.67,
151.13,
111.28,
29.515,
29.67,
158800,
167.15,
0.06802,
1179
])

constr_a = []

for i in range(numdim):

    constr_default = np.zeros(numdim)
    constr_default[i] = 1
    constr_a.append(constr_default)

for i in range(numdim):

    constr_default = np.zeros(numdim)
    constr_default[i] = -1
    constr_a.append(constr_default)

constr_a = np.asarray(constr_a)
constr_b = np.arange(1, 2*numdim + 1, 1)
constr_b[numdim:] = constr_b[:numdim]

print linprog(np.transpose(arr1 * arr2), constr_a, constr_b, bounds=(None, None))
```

I get the following result:

> **fun: -4327476.2887400016
>   message: 'Optimization failed. The problem appears to be unbounded.'
>   status: 3**

I've tried changing the last row to:

```
print linprog(np.transpose(arr1 * arr2), constr_a, constr_b, bounds=(-1000, 1000))
```

The numbers specified as bounds are random. The output is:

> **fun: -4327476.2887400296
>   message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
>   status: 0**

which gives us a slightly different result and the desired status.
My question is, do I misuse the library and in which way? Which answer is correct? This code was expected to work without specifying the 'bounds' parameter. I cannot use this parameter because these simple constraints are unique for each variable.

I use python 2.7 and scipy 0.17.1. Big thanks in advance.

**Upd**

`constr_a` should be a matrix according to the documentation (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.linprog-simplex.html) and actually is in the code. To be sure the syntax is correct, we can cut the number of dimensions to 2:

```
from scipy.optimize import linprog
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

numdim = 2

arr1 = np.ones(numdim)
arr1 = - arr1

arr2 = np.array([
19.53,
128.97
])

constr_a = []

for i in range(numdim):

    constr_default = np.zeros(numdim)
    constr_default[i] = 1
    constr_a.append(constr_default)

for i in range(numdim):

    constr_default = np.zeros(numdim)
    constr_default[i] = -1
    constr_a.append(constr_default)

constr_a = np.asarray(constr_a)
constr_b = np.arange(1, 2*numdim + 1, 1)
constr_b[numdim:] = constr_b[:numdim]

print constr_a
print constr_b
print linprog(np.transpose(arr1 * arr2), constr_a, constr_b, bounds=(None, None))
```

and this will work.

Answer (score 0):

the `constr_a` list is not properly formed. It is an array of array's instead of being an array of scalar. This might be leading to a improper lower bound causing the optimization to fail.

Perhaps

```
constr_a.append(constr_default)
```

should be

```
constr_a.append(constr_default[i])
```

inspect both the bound arrays to make sure they have proper form and values.

Comment: `constr_a` is a matrix (2n, n), unknown variables array is (n, 1), matrix-multiplication results in array `constr_b`, which is (2n, 1). Seems to me, no mistake here.

Comment: @Inna print and check the first few elements of `constr_a`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Answered in the post.